# Rest call with Restlet Framework

Tags: android, api, http, rest, restlet

I developp a android application, to collect orders saved on a web API.
I do my Rest call with the protocol http like this:

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

 try {
      HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://.../api/orders...");
      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
      HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
      if (httpEntity != null) {
          InputStream inputeStream = httpEntity.getContent();
      BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputeStream));
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

      String ligneLue = bufferReader.readLine();
      while (ligneLue != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(ligneLue + "\n");
        ligneLue = bufferReader.readLine();
      }
      bufferReader.close();
      SONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
          ...
          ...
          (I collect what I need.)
          ...
          ...
      }
```

Now I want to use the Framework restlet to do the  same think. it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible! The Restlet framework provides the ClientResource class for this:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://...");
Representation representation = cr.get();
JsonRepresentation jsonRepresentation = new JsonRepresentation(representation);
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonRepresentation.getJsonObject();
```

Be sure to have the org.restlet.jar and org.restlet.ext.json.jar (and its JSON lib dependency) files in your classpath. Take care to download the Restlet edition for Android that ensure that the framework will correctly work in the Java Android environment.

Hope it helps you.

Thierry